# Cakephp validate data on update entity

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, orm

I cannot get the validation to work properly when updating entity data. The validation does not work after changing the initial data. The code below provides an example:

```
    // in controller
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity([
        'mail' => 'wrong',
        'password' => 'password',
        'auth_level' => 0,
    ]);
    debug($user->getErrors()); // Will show error: wrong email format
    $user->mail = "correct@correct.correct";
    debug($user->getErrors()); // Will show no errors
    $user->mail = "wrong";
    debug($user->getErrors()); //Will show no errors

    if (TableRegistry::get('users')->save($user)) {
       // This actually executes
    }
```

My validation rule in the model is as follows:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
{
    $validator
        ->email('mail')
        ->add('mail', 'unique',
            [
                'on' => ['create', 'update'],
                'rule' => 'validateUnique',
                'provider' => 'table',
                'message' => "Email already in use"
            ]
        );
     return $validator
}
```

I tried creating rules with "on" => "update", but it does not help.

What I am trying to achieve is to get an entity, change the email address and save it back to database. Upon saving, the email field is neither validated for format nor uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness.

There is a difference between Application Rules and Validation Rules.

**Validation Rules** validate data typically coming from user's input (newEntity(), patchEntity()). Entity is regenerated. Baked ones are in "validationDefault" function within Tables.

**Application Rules** establish some rules for data modified within application code which is expected to be 'safe' (setters). Entity is not regenerated. Baked ones are in "buildRules" function within Tables.

"save()" function won't go through validation rules, but through application rules.

When saving data that needs to pass through validation rules because it's assigned/set within the application but it's data coming from user's input, make sure you use patchEntity().

More info: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6654

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to always update entity data with

```
$model->patchEntity($entity, $newdata)
```